# How to send data from a WindowsPhone7 to an Bing Map API built Html Page?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I need to push some data such as latitude and Longitude to a Bing Map from a Windows Phone 7 application. Any Idea?

My Scenario is that I created an PhoneApp and it will locate the users postion, now on the other side, using Bing API, I managed to bring up the map and PushPins and all that stuff, but in Jscript and HTML.

Now I'm stuck in the process in how to pass the values to the server side from the phone!

PS: in the start up I designed the application in a way to compose the detail of a location as an Email or SMS using the `Windows.Phone.Task` , but then I have no idea how to receive it on the Bing Map side and use it!

- Is there a way to have some sort of `Post` or `Get` Method to the
  html page from the phone?
- is wcf a suggestion? then how?

Comment: You're not using the bing map control for SL/WP7?

Comment: @DerekBeattie I'm using a GeoLocator on the Phone, and on the ServerSide, yes I have Bing Map supported by Silverlight....! I'm having a terrible time on finding a way to pass Latitude and Longitude from the Phone to the Server for the Bing Map!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sliverlight is client side also.  What you need is a service that the phone can send/post data to and the Silverlight app can get/receive data from.  On the Sliverlight side you could run a simple `DispatcherTimer` and when it fires, it refreshes an `ObservableCollection` of geolocations that the map is bound to.

edit: I should have mentioned that you'll probably want to persist the geolocations the phone is sending but I'm sure you already know that.

For the service you could use something like [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/), WCF, or ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: Exactly that is what I want! I will looking into this Thanks!